# How can I add something to a variable with a number

Tags: tikz-pgf

I currently have an image like this:

[image]

which is created by the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\R}{1.5} % radius of the circle
    \newcommand{\n}{6} % edges of the polygon

    % Center
    \path ( 0,0) coordinate (M);

    % Inner polygon
    \foreach \nr in {1, ..., \n}{
        \path (360/\n*\nr:\R) coordinate (i\nr);
        \draw (M) -- (i\nr);
    }
    \draw (0:0.3*\R) arc (0:360/\n:0.3*\R);
    \coordinate[label=right:$\alpha$] (Alpha) at ({2*360/(\n+2)}:0.1*\R);
    \draw (i1) -- (i2) -- (i3) -- (i4) --(i5) -- (i6) -- cycle;

    % Circle
    \draw[green] (0,0) circle (\R);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have code that is independent of n. So, at the moment, when I change `n` from 6 to 7 I get:

[image]

I know I have to change the following part:

```
\draw (i1) -- (i2) -- (i3) -- (i4) --(i5) -- (i6) -- cycle;
```

but this does not work:

```
\foreach \nr in {1, ..., \n-1}{
    \draw (M) -- (i{\nr+1});
}
```

It gives:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named i{1+1} is known.
```

The problem is that my math expression does not get evaluated, but I have no idea how I could make LaTeX evaluate it. How can I add something to a variable with a number?

Comment: not the answer to your question but you can use `\draw (i1) \foreach\x in{2,...,6}{--(i\x)};`. Otherwise you can use `\pgfmathparse{...}` to parse the math and then use `\pgfmathresult` whereever needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
\draw (i1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\n} {-- (i\i)} -- cycle;
```

to loop over all corners:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\R}{1.5} % radius of the circle
    \newcommand{\n}{5} % edges of the polygon

    % Center
    \path ( 0,0) coordinate (M);

    % Inner polygon
    \foreach \nr in {1, ..., \n}{
        \path (360/\n*\nr:\R) coordinate (i\nr);
        \draw (M) -- (i\nr);
    }
    \draw (0:0.3*\R) arc (0:360/\n:0.3*\R);
    \coordinate[label=right:$\alpha$] (Alpha) at ({2*360/(\n+2)}:0.1*\R);
    \draw (i1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\n} {-- (i\i)} -- cycle;

    % Circle
    \draw[green] (0,0) circle (\R);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```